# Angular 1.4: Progress bar not working properly

Tags: html, angularjs, progress-bar

So I have a main application from which we select some data and that data is passed onto a `microservice`, using `RabbitMQ`, where the data is processed. Now I am using `Pusher` to send back the number of items processed. It is working fine but when I pass that data to `progress bar`, it doesn't work properly, like it stops showing the bar after, for example, the count is 40. Here it is how I am doing it:

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
channel.bind('my-event', function (data) {
    if (data.message === 'Added') {
          $scope.totalProcessed++;
          $scope.processedPercentage = ($scope.totalProcessed / $scope.totalTOsSelectedForCo2Calculations * 100).toFixed(2);
          $scope.showPercentage = $scope.totalProcessed === $scope.totalTOsSelectedForCo2Calculations ? false : true;
     }
});
```

Here is my progress bar html:

```
<div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar"
             aria-valuenow="{{processedPercentage}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: {{ processedPercentage}}%">
            {{processedPercentage}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is an image of it stopping at 14.78 percent when the variable `$scope.totalTOsSelectedForCo2Calculations` has value of 203. What am I doing wrong here? How can I make it work?
[image]

Comment: Have you verified that `$scope.totalProcessed` is continuing to increment the entire time? Also, as a best practice, you should use `ng-style="{ 'width': processedPercentage + '%' }"`

Comment: @JacobStamm yes, when I print it in console, the value does increase but for some reason it does not reflect in the html. And thanks for the ng-style suggestion.